# Cannot login into Ubuntu 16.04 - Some kind of error

Tags: boot, login, live-usb, 16.04, bios

I'm unable to log in into Ubuntu 16.04. It is fresh installation from yesterday. Everything was working until I opened my PC today. I cannot believe that something like that happen. Could anyone help me with it? What should I do? I have Laptop HP Envy - i7 .

Even, please tell me how to open bootable USB Pendrive to install it one again. I Just have Ubuntu OS and I cannot see BIOS display. Ubuntu is loading from the start.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try to put a bootable Ubuntu USB into the USB and see if it will boot into that ... if not you will need to get into your BIOS and change the boot order so it will boot to the USB instead of the HD.

I tried looking it up and from what it seems for an envy notebook .. it is F10 so try hitting F10 as soon as you turn on the computer and continue to hit it over and over every half second or so and you should get into bios to change boot order. You cant hold it down or you will get a keyboard error this is why you have to rapidly tap the F10 key. There is a very small window in which to catch it. If the Ubuntu logo shows up ... you are too late and missed it.

It should be F10 but I didn't know what model envy you had ... it seems that the ones I checked all used F10 so that may be an HP standard.